# How do I serve an svg file as a web app in GAS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, google-apps-script

I'm trying to learn how to serve a series of static svg files as a web app in Google Apps Script. The files I want to serve are available at IcoMoon for which I have the code. I do not know how to apply them as a part of a web app. This is the code I have tried thus far:

```js
function doGet() {
    return createHtmlOutputFromFile('KI_SVG_Test');
       getContent()  
}
```

```css
<style>

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}

<style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--1-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://i.icomoon.io/public/e29d02ae9a/KernskyIntergraph/style-svg.css">
    <!--2-->
    <script defer src="https://i.icomoon.io/public/e29d02ae9a/KernskyIntergraph/svgxuse.js"></script>
    <!--3-->
    <svg class="icon icon-E000-uldf-f"><use xlink:href="#icon-E000-uldf-f"></use></svg>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <symbol id="icon-E000-uldf-f" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path d="M-25.942-16.073c0 0 0 0 0 0zM8.65 20.977c0 0 0 10.737 0 10.737s2.685 0 2.685 0c0 0 0-10.737 0-10.737s-2.685 0-2.685 0zM8.65 29.030c0 0 0 2.685 0 2.685s16.105 0 16.105 0c0 0 0-2.685 0-2.685s-16.105 0-16.105 0zM22.072 20.977c0 0 0 10.737 0 10.737s2.685 0 2.685 0c0 0 0-10.737 0-10.737s-2.685 0-2.685 0z"></path>
    </symbol>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone offer me any pointers as to how I can serve a single svg file as a web app in GAS?

Answer (score 1):

I have posted a working example of a web app that displays icoMoon svgs. I don't have a paid account with IcoMoon so I can't access all of their svgs. But I retrieved the one in this sample from the project's [Github page](https://github.com/Keyamoon/IcoMoon-Free)

[Working Example](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyrt5FKl3p0TIdbAMLlp3Hszuw9C3lI5Akvdv_E7wqmTmssNW3kTrishQ/exec)

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).setTitle("SVG Demo").addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!--1-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://i.icomoon.io/public/e29d02ae9a/KernskyIntergraph/style-svg.css">
    <!--2-->
    <script defer src="https://i.icomoon.io/public/e29d02ae9a/KernskyIntergraph/svgxuse.js"></script>
    <!--3-->
    <?!= include('style'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path fill="#000000" d="M16 9.226l-8-6.21-8 6.21v-2.532l8-6.21 8 6.21zM14 9v6h-4v-4h-4v4h-4v-6l6-4.5z"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.html

```
<style>
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;
}
</style>
```